# Importing a database from a custom built website into WordPress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am beginner to WordPress and never build a WordPress website before. Now I'm still in learning status, please bear with me.

Currently I'm using a WordPress template to build the website. I have a few mysql database tables from my custom built website, with the attributes like id, name, description, image(longblob field) etc. Now I'd like to integrate these tables into WordPress, so that my user no need to re-insert all the info to new website.

What would be the best way to do this? I have searched through some forum, some of them suggested using CSV. But I still have no idea how to do that as WordPress has different attributes with my database. The encoded image might has issue after exported in CSV format too.

Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question is very general.

Comment: There are two ways you can approach this, you can either leave the data in the database and then write a `php` script to loop through the database and convert them into `wordpress` posts etc.

OR 

You could export this data to a `csv` and then write an import script to import the data from the `csv` which will then create the relevant posts etc.

The choice is yours, both approaches are very similar but you both will have different advantages based off of how many times you will need to do this import.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Because I have no direction how to do that, can't even find a best question to ask. Helpless now.

Comment: @LewisBrowne Thank you so much for your suggestion :) May I know does CSV method works for image? And is that any WordPress plugin can use for import CSV?

Comment: CSV will work for images, ONLY if you specify the images location (url). Unfortunately you cannot import and image into a csv, but thats not much of an issue to solve. I would recommend writing a custom php script which does this instead of using a plugin. Just because your old website was custom, chances are that no one will know your post/page format.

Comment: @LewisBrowne do you have any example for writing a custom php script? I have no idea how to do that. I found a plugin named "WP All Import", it's pretty good but I need to purchase for the pro version to upload images and some add on functions.

Comment: Like i said, stay away from any plugins because your custom data probably won't work with them. In terms with writing the custom script you will need to read into working with csv's. If this is something you want writing for you email me at: lewisbrowne_9@hotmail.com

Comment: Okay! Thanks @LewisBrowne :)